# MATLAB: How to find the maximum vertical distance between two curves?

Tags: matlab, curves

I am interested in finding the x value at which the vertical distance between two curves is maximum. I don't know how to do this in Matlab (see the figure below for the graph)

[image: Graph]

I have my functions defined to be:

```
y1 = (1 - exp(-5))*exp(-x/50);
y2 = (1 - exp(-5000/1600))*exp(-x/250);
x = 10:300;
```

Does anyone know how I can locate the maximum vertical distance between these two graphs in the interval 10 to 300? Thank you for your time

Comment: If you are not interested in finding the maximum analytically, then plot $y_1-y_2$, or check out `max` function in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`[M,I] = max(abs(y1-y2))`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) gives the desired maximum value `M` and the corresponding first index `I`.

```
x = 10:300;
y1 = (1 - exp(-5))*exp(-x/50);
y2 = (1 - exp(-5000/1600))*exp(-x/250);
[M,I] = max(abs(y1-y2));
display([M,x(I)])  # return: 0.50663   103.00000
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for